# R blogdown is not showing the figure

Tags: r, r-markdown, blogdown

I am trying to add this picture below to my blog

[image]

It generates an html file like this:

[image]

However, when I run `blogdown::serve_site`, the actual website appears without figure like this below:
[image]

Can someone please suggest me a solution to fix this issue?

Comment: It's hard to tell if you don't provide a reproducible example.

Comment: @YihuiXie Hi, I have this markdown file, line 430, where I tried to include graphics. 
https://github.com/achalneupane/achalneupane/blob/main/content/post/Deep_learning/deep_learning.rmd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include arbitrary files under the same directory as the Rmd file, you must use a [leaf bundle](https://gohugo.io/content-management/page-bundles/). That is, your Rmd file must be named `index.Rmd` under a directory.

There exists an alternative way, but it's much less intuitive, which is [the `static/` folder](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/static-files.html).

Comment: Thank you so much. Just renaming the file to index.rmd worked.